# Arrow keys doesn't work in GRUB

Tags: 16.04, grub2

When I boot my machine I come to the GRUB menu that lists Ubuntu 16.04 and three other headings under that, one of which is Windows 10.

When I try to use my arrow keys to move down the menu the selection won't scroll. Thus I can only boot Ubuntu. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do the arrow keys work in the BIOS?

Comment: If you have a keyboard with a 10-Key pad on it, if you turn off the NumLock, you can use the 8 and 2 keys for up and down.

Comment: If you're using a wireless keyboard (like a Logitech), that may happen. You'll need to connect a hard-wired keyboard to fix this problem. Also, the GRUB menu doesn't scroll... just the highlighted option changes when you use the arrow keys... unless you've modified the grub color defaults in /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme.

Comment: I turned the NumLock off and used both the F2 and F8 key and the 2 and 8 key - no response. I can't enter safe mode or bios using the F keys. I  press the enter key and go immediately to Ubuntu bootup, or I can wait and go there. I have not modified the grub color defaults and my keyboard is hard wired into a USB port.

Comment: I have another issue as well. When I do updates the progress box will go monochrome as if the computer is laboring. I also occasionally get an error message and the update won't download. Sometimes I can go to the Ubuntu software button, select updates and it will work there. Thanks for your help! Appreciated.

Comment: If you use the right-arrow it goes to the system directly. Only down arrow works. Of course you might have already known this. Just a thought.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? If so can you answer your own question? If it's working now but you don't remember how it got fixed can you let us know? Thanks.